# ApolloProvider not found in testing with MockedProvider

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

Using Jest, Enzyme, and "@apollo/react-hooks" 3.1.5

I am getting:

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an , or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options.

However, from my research I believe MockedProvider should handle this. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: SUBMIT_FORM,
      variables: { name: 'Buck' },
    },
     result: {
       foo: 'sss'
     },
  },
];

describe('CustomForm', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
  });

  describe('When a user submits a form', () => {
    it('will send a event if mount poinmt is found', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(
        <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
          <CustomForm
            form={completeForm}
          />
        </MockedProvider>
      )
    });
  });
});
```